# Should templates be used when type-parameter-specific code is needed?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Imagine we have a class responsible for setting values for SQL prepared statements like these:

```
void MySqlPreparedStatement::SetString(uint32_t paramIndex, const std::string& value);
void MySqlPreparedStatement::SetBinary(uint32_t paramIndex, const void* value, size_t length);
void MySqlPreparedStatement::SetUInt64(uint32_t paramIndex, const uint64_t value);
void MySqlPreparedStatement::SetInt64(uint32_t paramIndex, const int64_t value);
// ...
```

All these "set" methods have code that is common among them but still have some code that depends on the type of the value the user is setting in (e.g. `m_parameters[paramIndex].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;` for 64 bit integers and `m_parameters[paramIndex].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;` for 32 bits integers).

In this case, which one is a better practice? Encapsulate all of these "set" methods in only one template method (which will make me create some switch/case on each accepted type-argument to get the correct value for `buffer_type`) or just declare different methods for each accepted type of value like the declarations I showed above?

Comment: constexpr if is your friend here, along with [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Comment: I don't think there's a general purpose advice that won't be opinionated. Personally, I prefer a bunch of small overloads over one monolith function template.

Comment: @Aconcagua 'll take a look. However do you have anything to add on which one would be the best practice? To overload the methods or use one template method?

Comment: A templated function, at its most basic, is essentially a specification of an unbounded family of related functions that all do (largely) similar operations.  From what you describe, you have a small family of functions (for string, arbitrary data, 32-bit integers (both signed and unsigned), and 64-bit integers (both signed and unsigned) - each of which is associated with some unique behaviour (e.g. the value given to `m_parameters[paramIndex].buffer_type`).   Based on that, I'd write a small set of overloaded functions, rather than a template.

Comment: Coming back to @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica 's comment: You could encapsulate the common code in one template function and have another template function `setAttribute` that you'd specialise for each type separately. Common code encapsulated in one template function, differing code in minimal small separate functions...

Comment: @Aconcagua could you elaborate why using template in this scenario is better than overloading methods for each different value type?

Comment: @andresantacruz Templates have the advantage that you can define one and the same equivalent behaviour for different types. Consider a `std::vector`, it does all the same no matter if it is instantiated as int, double or class type. Similar your functions, they share quite some common code, as you mentioned yourself. You can avoid duplicating code that way.

Comment: @Aconcagua but in this case, the shared code can be encapsulated in a regular simple regular method, it doesn't need to be a template method.

Comment: @andresantacruz So common code is 100% identical, independent from type of arguments. Then templates don't really appear suitable. Be aware that each template instantiation is a separate function, and you'd duplicate compiled code then. So having minimal (possibly inlined) functions all calling that common (possibly appropriately parametrised) function likely is preferrable...

Comment: Would variable templates be appropriate?
`template <typename T>
constexpr auto buffer_type;
template <>
constexpr auto buffer_type<uint32_t> = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
template <>
constexpr auto buffer_type<uint64_t> = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;`

Comment: @Kerndog73 Thought of something similar myself already. But that's only of value if we indeed opt for creating a template function...

Answer (score 1):

What is most suitable depends heavily on the code contained in the functions.

If you can clearly separate specific code and common *identical* code, then encapsulating this identical code in a separate function and call that one from smaller functions containing the specific parts might be more suitable (shortening signature a bit):

```
void setUInt64(uint64_t value)
{
    // some code specific to uint64_t, maybe converting to binary or textual representation
    setParameter(/*...*/, sizeof(value), MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG);
}
```

(According to your comments, that seems to be the case in your concrete example.)

Matter changes, though, if you have common code and specific code intermixed (extending the point of view):

```
void setInt32(int32_t value)
{
    firstCommonFunction(/*...*/);
    // some specific code
    secondCommonFunction(/*...*/);
}
```

Would you really want to implement that pattern for every function? While above might be a corner case, you're better off with a template if the function gets even more complex:

```
template <typename T>
void setParameter(T const& value)
{
    firstCommonFunction(/*...*/);
    firstSpecificFunction<T>(/*...*/);
    secondCommonFunction(/*...*/);
    secondSpecificFunction<T>(/*...*/);
    thirdCommonFunction(/*...*/);
    thirdSpecificFunction<T>(/*...*/);
    fourthCommonFunction(/*...*/);
}
```

Now a template assures that all your functions behave alike, calling common and specific functions whenever appropriate.

That's fine if your functions all look like that by design anyway. However, artificially enforcing such a design by all means solely for the sake of being able to have a template usually is not that a good idea...